# windows right single quote error when copying data into postgres from csv file

Tags: postgresql, encoding, copy, command

i'm trying to import csv file into a postgres db (ver 9.3, with database encoding set as UTF8).  using the command below, i get the error (also below)

```
copy mytable from 'C:/candidate_analyze.csv' delimiter ',' csv;

ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x96
```

after researching, i see that this error is related Windows-1252 or the windows version of the right single quote mark instead of apostrophe.

there is a text field in the csv file (called "orig_text") that has the right single quote mark in it.

this copy functionality is something that is going to be automated,  so i can't go in there and manuually do a search and replace for the windows right quote mark everytime.

any ideas as to a solution to this problem?

any help would be greatly appreciated.   thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`COPY` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) has an `ENCODING` option:

> `ENCODING`
>   Specifies that the file is encoded in the `encoding_name`. If this option is omitted, the current client encoding is used.

So if your file really is encoded in windows-1252 then you could say:

```
copy mytable from 'C:/candidate_analyze.csv' delimiter ',' encoding 'windows-1252' csv;
```